# AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute '__tojava__'

Tags: jython

I browsed the javadoc for PyInteger and found it supports api **tojava**. However, when I run the following script, error happens.

```
n=1
n.__tojava__(java.math.BigInteger)
```

**AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute '_*tojava*_'**

I found only the api which is written with pure python could be called successfully. For other apis, there are always errors, saying "xxx object has no attribute 'xxx'". Is there any configuration I should do?

Answer (score 0):

if all you want is a BigInteger, you an just construct an instance using the string constructor

> x=java.math.BigInteger('1')

or in your case

> x=java.math.BigInteger(str(n))